# Can an application built with VC++ 2010 run reliably with just the VC++ 2013 redistributable installed?

Tags: visual-c++, software-distribution

So here is my situation: We have some applications built using VC++ 2010, but others are now built with VC++ 2013.

In the past, when setting up a client machine, only VC++ 2010 Redistributable was installed, but with the development of some of these applications now in VC++ 2013 we need to install the VC++ 2013 Redistributable.

I know that the Redistributable packages are installed side by side and that applications developed in VC++ 2010 will go to their appropriate file set if it exists on the machine.

But can a VC++ 2010 project run reliably with just the VC++ 2013 redistributable installed?

This question occurred to be when I saw that Microsoft named the VC++ 2010 and 2013 redistributable install files the same. For example, **vcredist_x86.exe**.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your VS2010 built app will need msvcr100.dll (etcetera), the VS2013 installer will deploy msvcr120.dll

Doing anything to force VS2010 to use the VS2013 runtime library is very unlikely to turn out well.  The new C++11 language standard has caused *lots* of upheaval in the runtime libraries.  The good kind of upheaval, but not exactly very compatible with old compilers.

You must therefore install the VS2010 runtime libraries as well.